# Reorder JList and ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, list, sorting, collections

So I have a GUI component where a JList is dependant upon an ArrayList of tasks. This Task object has a specific index and I want the JList to reflect that specific order. This is no problem so far.
The problem is that I want the user to drag and drop the objects inside the JList to change the order. I want the ArrayList (which supports the Jlist) to also reflect those changes.

Here is my TransferHandler class :

```
class ListItemTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {
    private final DataFlavor localObjectFlavor;
    private Object[] transferedObjects = null;

    public ListItemTransferHandler() {
        localObjectFlavor = new ActivationDataFlavor(Object[].class, DataFlavor.javaJVMLocalObjectMimeType, "Array of items");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent c) {
        JList list = (JList) c;
        indices = list.getSelectedIndices();
        transferedObjects = list.getSelectedValues();
        return new DataHandler(transferedObjects, localObjectFlavor.getMimeType());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canImport(TransferSupport info) {
        if (!info.isDrop() || !info.isDataFlavorSupported(localObjectFlavor)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
        return MOVE; // TransferHandler.COPY_OR_MOVE;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public boolean importData(TransferSupport info) {
        if (!canImport(info)) {
            return false;
        }
        JList target = (JList) info.getComponent();
        JList.DropLocation dl = (JList.DropLocation) info.getDropLocation();
        DefaultListModel listModel = (DefaultListModel) target.getModel();
        int index = dl.getIndex();
        int max = listModel.getSize();
        if (index < 0 || index > max) {
            index = max;
        }
        addIndex = index;
        try {
            Object[] values = (Object[]) info.getTransferable().getTransferData(localObjectFlavor);
            addCount = values.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                int idx = index++;
                listModel.add(idx, values[i]);
                target.addSelectionInterval(idx, idx);
            }
            return true;
        } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException ufe) {
            ufe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void exportDone(JComponent c, Transferable data, int action) {
        cleanup(c, action == MOVE);
    }

    private void cleanup(JComponent c, boolean remove) {
        if (remove && indices != null) {
            JList source = (JList) c;
            DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel) source.getModel();
            if (addCount > 0) {
                // http://java-swing-tips.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/DnDReorderList/src/java/example/MainPanel.java
                for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
                    if (indices[i] >= addIndex) {
                        indices[i] += addCount;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = indices.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                model.remove(indices[i]);
            }
        }
        indices = null;
        addCount = 0;
        addIndex = -1;
    }

    private int[] indices = null;
    private int addIndex = -1; // Location where items were added
    private int addCount = 0; // Number of items added.
}
```

How would I implement this feature? I suppose this would help but the Task objects implements Comparable to sort.

Comment: Don't keep data in two places. The ListModel should contain the data. There is no need for the ArrayList. The DefaultListModel uses a Vector to hold the data. If you don't like that then create a custom ListModel that uses an ArrayList.

Comment: independent on the concrete implemenation: you either can have the list sorted or allow the user to re-arrange them, not both. Or - if the re-arrange would imply a re-indexing of the task - you need to implement some logic doing it. Best to show a SSCCE that demonstrates the behaviour as-is and explain what you want exactly with that example.